# Herb Sutter's 10-liner with cleanup

Tags: c++, caching, mutex

I've been adding data caching to my code and remembered "Herb Sutter's favorite 10-liner.":

```cpp
shared_ptr<widget> get_widget(int id) {
    static map<int, weak_ptr<widget>> cache;
    static mutex m;

    lock_guard<mutex> hold(m);
    auto sp = cache[id].lock();
    if (!sp) cache[id] = sp = load_widget(id);
    return sp;
}
```

The one criticism I've seen of this is that, depending on context, it may be a problem that nothing is ever removed from the cache.

I was surprised I couldn't find the clean-up-after-itself solution anywhere. What do you think of this?

```cpp
std::shared_ptr<widget> get_widget(int id) {
    static std::map<int, std::weak_ptr<widget>> cache;
    static std::mutex m;

    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> hold(m);
    auto& weakCached = cache[id]; // Keep a reference so we don't hae to call this non-nothrow function below.
    auto sp = weakCached.lock();
    if (!sp) {
        std::unique_ptr<widget> it = load_widget(id);
        // We have to be careful about the deleter not being
        // called while in the mutex lock 'cause that'd be a 
        // double lock => deadlock.
        // For that reason, we already have a 
        auto deleter = [&,id,d=it.get_deleter()](widget* w) {
            std::lock_guard<std::mutex> hold(m);
            d(w);
            cache.erase(id);
        };
        sp = std::shared_ptr<widget>(it.get(), deleter);
        it.release(); // In the case that the above line throws, we won't hit this line and so won't leak.
        weakCached = sp;
    }
    return sp;
}
```

As the comment says, the part that gives me pause is the transfer of ownership to the `deleter` function. In particular, the fact that calling it locks the mutex, so it can't be called while the mutex is locked. I think this correctly guarantees that it won't be called inside the critical section, particularly because if `sp = std::shared_ptr<widget>(it.get(), deleter);` throws, then it's still owned by the `unique_ptr` and the following line lets it go.

Bonus points: What if `load_widget(int id)` returns a `std::shared_ptr<widget>` which could already have a non-trivial deleter. Is there a way to inject this wrapper around it, or is that not possible?

Comment: This question may be a better fit for [codereview.se] with some small modifications

Comment: Why does the `std::map` hold `std::weak_ptr` instead of `std::shared_ptr`? Seems to me that unless `load_widget()` returns a `std::shared_ptr`, there is potential here for the cached `std::weak_ptr`s to usually be null when the caller is done using the returned `std::shared_ptr`s. Not much of a good cache, now is it?

Comment: If the `std::map` held `std::shared_ptr`s, then the refcount would never go to zero and so the objects would live forever. That's desirable behavior for some caches, but the idea here is that the cache is used so long as someone still has that entry to keep it alive. In the original implementation, you "leak" `std::weak_ptr`s in that they never get cleaned up. My change tries to fix that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe there is a simpler way to guarantee that the deleter won't run while `hold` *holds the* lock: Declare `sp` before `hold`, so when we go out of scope, the mutex will be released before the deleter can run:

```
std::shared_ptr<widget> sp;
std::lock_guard<std::mutex> hold(m);
auto& weakCached = cache[id];
sp = weakCached.lock();
```

It makes sense to reuse `weakCached` even without having to care about exception safety.

---

> What if `load_widget(int id)` returns a `std::shared_ptr<widget>`

Here's an (wild?) idea:

```
std::shared_ptr<widget> it = load_widget(id);
widget* ptr = it.get();
auto deleter = [&,id,original=std::move(it)](widget*) {
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> hold(m);
    cache.erase(id);
};
weakCached = sp = std::shared_ptr<widget>(ptr, std::move(deleter));
```

We keep a copy of the result from `load_widget` in the deleter. This causes our shared pointer to keep the original shared pointer alive. When our refcount is exhausted, our custom deleter doesn't do anything to the widget directly. The deleter is simply destroyed, and so the captured shared pointer is destroyed, and if it is the only owner, then the original custom deleter does its job.

This approach has a caveat: If a copy of the original shared pointer is somehow available elsewhere, then its lifetime may be extended beyond the lifetime of our shared pointer, and so the cache may be purged prematurely. Whether this is the case, and whether this is a problem depend on the widget API in question.

This approach can be used with your unique pointer case as well.

Comment: Interesting. I really like your first part. That totally fixes the icky part of my solution, I think.

For the second part... interesting. It's kinda icky, but I think it's correct. It's icky in that you have two distinct `shared_ptr`s to the same object with their own reference counts, and you've structured it such that instead of directly deleting the original copy, the "outer" `shared_ptr` does the `cache` bookkeeping. Interesting point that the same approach can be used with the `unique_ptr`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an extended version of the code which can be used for a collection of types. The Factory also ensures that each object is uniquely created, which allows for efficient comparison and hashing of the underlying objects of the shared_ptrs because we can simply compare by the pointers and take the pointer as hash value. It requires for each type:

1. a constructor that takes an `int` as first argument which should also be private since we want the factory to be the only creator of the objects;
2. injection of a hash function in the `std` namespace;
3. equality comparison operator.

```cpp
#include <unordered_map>
#include <unordered_set>
#include <memory>
#include <mutex>
#include <tuple>


template<typename... Ts>
class ReferenceCountedObjectFactory {
private:

    /// @brief Encapsulates the data of a single type.
    template<typename T>
    struct PerTypeCache {
        std::unordered_set<T> uniqueness;
        std::unordered_map<int, std::weak_ptr<const T>> identifier_to_object;
    };

    /// @brief Encapsulates the data of all types.
    struct Cache {
        std::tuple<PerTypeCache<Ts>...> data;
        // Identifiers are shared across types since types can be polymorphic
        int count = 0;
        // Mutex is shared for thread-safe changes to count that is shared across types
        std::mutex mutex;
    };

    std::shared_ptr<Cache> m_cache;

public:
    ReferenceCountedObjectFactory()
        : m_cache(std::make_shared<Cache>()) { }

    /// @brief Gets a shared reference to the object of type T with the given arguments.
    ///        If such an object does not exists then it creates one.
    /// @tparam ...Args The arguments that are passed to the constructor of T.
    /// @param ...args
    /// @return
    template<typename T, typename... Args>
    [[nodiscard]] std::shared_ptr<const T> get_or_create(Args&&... args) {
        /* we must declare sp before locking the mutex
           s.t. the deleter is called after the mutex was released in case of stack unwinding. */
        std::shared_ptr<T> sp;
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> hold(m_cache->mutex);

        auto& t_cache = std::get<PerTypeCache<T>>(m_cache->data);
        int identifier = m_cache->count;
        auto key = T(identifier, args...);
        const auto& [it, inserted] = t_cache.uniqueness.insert(key);
        if (!inserted) {
            assert(t_cache.identifier_to_object.count(it->get_identifier()));
            return t_cache.identifier_to_object.at(it->get_identifier()).lock();
        }
        ++m_cache->count;
        /* Must explicitly call the constructor of T to give exclusive access to the factory. */
        // Extensions: To ensure that the memory for T and the control block is allocated once,
        // we could use std::allocated_shared and provide a custom allocator.
        sp = std::shared_ptr<T>(
            new T(identifier, args...),
            [cache=m_cache, identifier](T* x)
            {
                {
                    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> hold(cache->mutex);
                    auto& t_cache = std::get<PerTypeCache<T>>(cache->data);
                    t_cache.uniqueness.erase(*x);
                    t_cache.identifier_to_object.erase(identifier);
                }
                /* After cache removal, we can call the objects destructor
                    and recursively call the deleter of children if their ref count goes to 0 */
                delete x;
            }
        );
        t_cache.identifier_to_object.emplace(identifier, sp);
        return sp;
    }
};
```